# How to activate debug mode for Terraform in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I would like to print more logs in Terraform using Azure pipeline, no need to export the logs in a file as the Terraform's documentation mentions.

Comment: have you tried running the pipeline with Enable System Diagnostics checked? I do that and get what I need. I do also output my log sometimes to a text file using TF_LOG. It is cumbersome though.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by setting the [TF_LOG](https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging#debugging-terraform) environment variable to one of the values below (most likely [`DEBUG`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-troubleshoot-terraform#enabling-debug-mode) in your case), in a separate task before you start running actual Terraform commands.

> - TRACE: the most elaborate verbosity, as it shows every step taken by    Terraform and produces enormous outputs with internal logs.
> - DEBUG: describes what happens internally in a more concise way compared to  TRACE.
> - ERROR: shows errors that prevent Terraform from continuing.
> - WARN: logs warnings, which may indicate misconfiguration or mistakes,    but are not critical to execution.
> - INFO: shows general, high-level    messages about the execution process

Bash:

```bash
export TF_LOG=<log_level>
```

PowerShell

```
$env:TF_LOG = '<log_level>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [TerraformTask](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks) in my pipeline. To enable debug logging, I set the `TF_LOG` environment variable in the following way:

```
- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  displayName: Run terraform apply
  env:
    TF_LOG: DEBUG
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'apply'
    commandOptions: '-auto-approve plan.tfplan'
    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: $(myServiceConnection)
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/myWorkingDirectory/'
```